# Android: How to catch Fatal Exception thrown from a referenced library?

Tags: android, exception, try-catch

I am using a referenced library called 'rome-1.0.jar'.

```
try {
    SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
    SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(file));
}
catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("", "ROME parse error: " + e.toString());
}
```

input.build(new XmlReader(file)); is 'rome-1.0.jar' library call.

Although I am catching all Exceptions, my app still crashes.

```
05-31 13:43:06.297: W/dalvikvm(11150): threadid=22: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4d1f8)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4199
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.beans.PropertyDescriptor[]
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.impl.BeanIntrospector.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanIntrospector.java:39)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.impl.CloneableBean.beanClone(CloneableBean.java:129)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.impl.ObjectBean.clone(ObjectBean.java:87)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.module.DCModuleImpl.clone(DCModuleImpl.java:771)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.module.impl.ModuleUtils.cloneModules(ModuleUtils.java:35)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.impl.ConverterForRSS090.createSyndEntry(ConverterForRSS090.java:90)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.impl.ConverterForRSS091Userland.createSyndEntry(ConverterForRSS091Userland.java:85)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.impl.ConverterForRSS092.createSyndEntry(ConverterForRSS092.java:46)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.impl.ConverterForRSS093.createSyndEntry(ConverterForRSS093.java:37)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.impl.ConverterForRSS094.createSyndEntry(ConverterForRSS094.java:58)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.impl.ConverterForRSS090.createSyndEntries(ConverterForRSS090.java:79)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.impl.ConverterForRSS090.copyInto(ConverterForRSS090.java:64)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.impl.ConverterForRSS091Userland.copyInto(ConverterForRSS091Userland.java:49)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.impl.ConverterForRSS094.copyInto(ConverterForRSS094.java:47)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeedImpl.<init>(SyndFeedImpl.java:144)
05-31 13:43:06.307: E/AndroidRuntime(11150):    at com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput.build(SyndFeedInput.java:123)
...(my code)
```

Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you Kumar, you gave me an idea.

I didn't know this was an error.
I have handled OutOfMemoryError before so I know I am able to handle errors.

```
try {
    SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
    SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(file));
}
catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("", "ROME parse error: " + e.toString());
}
catch(Error e2) {
    Log.e("", "ROME parse error2: " + e2.toString());
}
```

Above code handles errors. I know it's not a good idea to do so, but it serves my purpose.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an exception, rather an error, whose nature is more severe than exceptions. You are not supposed to handle errors.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/269746/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Error-vs-Exception

If errors happen, the system will, in most of the cases become unstable, and you really can't do anything about it.